# Выезжайка JQuery

Tags: jquery, css

У меня есть "выезжайка" на jquery(блок который выезжает вниз меняя свою высоту), под ней есть контент... так вот, когда он выезжает, контент, что внизу сьезжает... как с этим бороться?

p.s. z-index проблему не решает
p.p.s не предлагайте позиционировать абсолютно

Comment: А куда должен деваться контент, который оказался внизу?

Comment: Оставаться на месте. А выезжающий блок должен просто перекрывать его сверху.

Comment: Можно одновременно прятать нижний блок, тогда это будет называться accordion. Например http://jqueryui.com/demos/accordion/

Answer (score 1):

Название вопроса супер просто. ) Может вам просто какой-нибудь готовый лайтбокс взять типа [fancybox](http://fancybox.net/)? Мучений в разы меньше будет. )